# Shuffle random list of COMMANDS in BASH?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a list of commands in a text file named commands.txt:

```
cat file1.txt | sort > file1.txt
cat file2.txt | sort > file2.txt
etc
```

What I want to do is randomize that file and then execute each line in random order. I have tried the following in a cmd.sh shell script:

```
while read -r -a array
do
    "${array[@]}"
done < <(shuf commands.txt)
```

And all Bash does is yell at me that it's a syntax error with an unexpected token <

This is on MacOS 10.14 with bash 3.2.57 and zsh 5.8.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Reading from a file that you redirect output to truncates the file. So you basically just clean all the files.

Comment: You are executing your script with `/bin/sh` which does not implement process substitutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the shuffled commands to bash without any processing:

```
shuf commands.txt | bash
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pipes (`|`) and redirection (`>`) will not work in a variable. You can use `eval "${array[@]}"`, or `bash -c "${array[*]}"` instead.

Also if you do `cat file > file`, `file` will be truncated (emptied) before `cat` is executed. So you'll just have empty files. You can do `sort file1.txt > tmp && mv tmp file1.txt`